# Magento 2 : CSV import-export error

Tags: magento2

I have custom attribute named style (http://prntscr.com/mq8run). 

It was perfecttly working till now. Import-export also working fine. But yesterday when I export CSV of product. All the products without style attribute, got style=11 in CSV. I create another CSV and remove style from all products and again Import CSV. It works fine style=11 removed from frontend also. But again i export CSV and found style=136 in all products (https://prnt.sc/mq7hwh)

I can't understand why this is happened.

Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: do you have one of the options for the style attribute marked as default?

Comment: Yes, But i remove it. 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. 
  **The problem was :**  When style attribute created it has default value. When i delete default value from style attribute it removes value from style attribute. But style attribute was already  assigned to all products with no any value. So it takes any random value when we export CSV. When i found out that problem i replace style in all products. So it is removed from every product.